# EfDbContext Connection Creates New Database, Causes FK Error

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I have a working MVC4 application. We recently decided to give LINQPad a try for testing and scripting stuff. While I can get it to access our databases directly, when I try to get it to connect using our backend EfDbContext, it reads the DLL correctly and shows all of the POCOs, but every query results in:

`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Seekers_dbo.Companies_CompanyID' on table 'Seekers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`

I can see a UserQuery database is created each time I try to get a top x of any table. I have it pointing to the Web.config which holds the connectionString for the DB connection. When I put the connection string in the App.config for the backend and point to that, I get the same error.

Using the Profiler, I can see that when I set up a connection and test it, LINQPad queries to database it is supposed to. It's only when I try to do `X.Take(100)` where I get issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the original POCOs weren't set up correctly, and when they were fixed testing hadn't caught the issues. After assigning correct foreign key annotations, it appears to be working.

UPDATE:

The fixes to make it "work" with LINQPad actually broke **a lot** of things, so I'm reverting it back to how we had it and assuming there's an issue with LinqPad not [querying the correct database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243088/linqpad-test-looks-for-correct-db-but-queries-wrong-one) as expected.