# LinqPad Test Looks For Correct DB But Queries Wrong One

Tags: linqpad

I have created a connection in LINQPad that uses a project's EfDBContext. After [some recent issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193732/efdbcontext-connection-creates-new-database-causes-fk-error) I can now get it to query a table, but when it does it created a whole new schema.

So, when creating the connection (Entity Framework POCO Connection), when I click "Test" the Profiler shows me:

`SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'mydatabase'`

But when I run `Ethnicities.Take (100)` I see:

`SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'UserQuery'`

Followed by all the commands to generate the schema. What am I doing wrong or need to change to get it to read the data in `mydatabase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/49460-linqpad-entity-framework-41-poco-query-problem/

And adding this line of code in my DbContext file fixed it:

`public EfDbContext() : base("mydatabase") { }`

Unsure if this is still a known bug or an issue with me, since I tried the beta and still had the same issue.